# How to find the frequency band of specified access point

Tags: java, android

I am using the following code to find all access points near to me.

We start the scanner with

```
registerReceiver(wifiReceiver, new IntentFilter(WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION));
wifiManager.startScan();
```

and get the results using a `BroadcastReceiver`

```
BroadcastReceiver wifiReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        List<ScanResult> scanResults = wifiManager.getScanResults();
        unregisterReceiver(this);

        for (ScanResult result : scanResults) {
            //some code...
        }
    }
};
```

Now, by using `ScanResults` we can get features like `ssid`, `bssid` or `capabilities` etc. but I can't find a way to get ssid's frequency band. Is it possible?

Comment: what do you mean by band? the channel or frequency?

Comment: I am talking about the two frequency bands, 2,4GHz and 5GHz

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In [`ScanResult`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/ScanResult.html), the [`frequency`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/ScanResult.html#frequency) field is how you can determine the band of the AP.

Specifically, the band would be 5GHz if `frequency` > 5000, and 2.4GHz if 3000 > `frequency` > 2000 (around 2400).

According to the [802.11 standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_802.11), it specifies that the 5GHz band's starting frequency is 5000MHz and 2.4GHz band's starting frequency is 2047MHz, the frequency you get from `ScanResult#frequency` will differ because of the different channels they are in.

---

The specific formula that converts the starting (base) frequency to the center (result) frequency is

```
freqCenter = freqStart + 5 * channelNumber
```

With that, you can derivate the channel number of the AP.